# Using a local variable out of an event handler function that makes an ajax call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, select, eventhandler

What would be the best way to get the value of the variable "search" from the first function to use it on the last ajax call? I know I could use closure but not sure how. Here's my code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".box", function(){
    var search = $(this).attr("alt");
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: url + search,
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
    })
});

$( ".select" ).change(function(){
 var param2 = $(this).val();
 $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: url + search + param2,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Do you have multiple `.box`s on your page? If not, why not just store it in a constant in your JavaScript code?

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately I have multiple...

Comment: Just declare the variable outside the two functions and it will be accessible within both. And add a test in the change handler to confirm it has been set (in case the user changes the select value without having clicked on a box).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a closure is as simple as declaring the variable outside the scope of both functions:

```
var search;

$(document).on("click", ".box", function(){
  search = $(this).attr("alt");
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: url + search,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  })
});

$( ".select" ).change(function(){
 var param2 = $(this).val();
 $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: url + search + param2,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  })
});
```